# Does $f$ have a limit if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$. Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists?

I think it's true since I fail to see a counter example, but I don't see how to use the boundedness in order to exclude functions like the logarithm. How to tackle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sin (\log x)$ does the trick - it oscillates from $-1$ to $1$ indefinitely and its derivative is $1/x \cos ( \log x)$ which goes to zero.

Edit: As Daniel pointed out, this isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, but the modification $\sin (\log (1+x^2))$ still works.

Comment: The question asks for an $f$ that is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, to get that, you need to make a small modification, e.g. $\sin (\log (1+x^2))$.

Comment: An intuitive way to look at this function is that it oscillates indefinitely, but the period of one oscillation gets indefinitely large.

Comment: @DanielFischer right, thanks.