# If $\lim_{x\to\infty} |f^\prime(x)|=0$ and $f^\prime(x)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, does this imply that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I know some counterexamples where either $|f^\prime(x)|$ or $f(x)$ are not continuous. Now, I just can't come up with a counterexample where both $|f^\prime(x)|$ and $f(x)$ are continuous. I'd appreciate it if somebody could help.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ on $0 \lt x \in \Bbb{R}$? Or are your limits in the extended reals?

Comment: @Ben I would say that $\lim \ln(x)$ exists (and is equal to $+\infty$...)

Comment: Just made an edit to the comment

Comment: I am not familiar to the extended reals, but do we say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists when $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \infty$?

Comment: $\sin(\ln(x))$ on $0<x$?

Comment: and just modifying @Gerd's suggestion slightly, if you really want a ($C^{\infty}$) function defined on $\Bbb{R}$, then look at $f(x)=\sin(\ln(1+x^2))$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo / Gerd Ah ja, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the quick help guys!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3055363/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607014/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600562/42969.